# Using translations provided by module(using ngx-translate module) in application

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, ng-packagr

I have an application A1 containing module M1, which uses ngx-translate module.
Module M1 is exported by ng-packagr and used by application A2 which also uses ngx-translate module.
What i have noticed is TranslateHttpLoader loads the language files from host application.
And somehow i want to forcefully use languages provided by the module instead of languages from application.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Sample code in module M1 :

```
   export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
        return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
    }

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            HttpClientModule,
            TranslateModule.forChild({
                loader: {
                    provide: TranslateLoader,
                    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                    deps: [HttpClient]
                }
            })
        ],
        ...
    })
    export class SomeModule { ... }
```

Thank You.

Comment: did you figure out how to fix this?

Comment: No.. Not yet...